# how to calculate all possible combinations with the lowest diviation between the combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, combinations, python-itertools

I have 3 lists:

```
a = {1:10,2:12,3:14}
b = {1:5,2:4,3:8}
c = {1:6,2:7,3:3}
```

Now i can get all the permutations with itertools

```
from itertools import combinations
input = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(input, i))) for i in range(len(input) + 1)], [])
```

but now my question is "How do i calculate the total number adding **a + b + c** together for each combination and getting the lowest deviation between them.

It also has to make sure that no index is used more then once.

So for example we could do:

```
A1 + B3 + C2 = 10 + 8 + 7 = 25
A2 + B1 + C1 = 12 + 5 + 6 = 23
A3 + B2 + C3 = 14 + 4 + 3 = 21
```

so we can see that we have a deviation of 4 (from highest to lowest). i am not 1005 sure if thats the best combo but its just for demonstration.

This program should be able to adapt itself to work with more values.

The list "A" will never be larger then "B" or "C" as they can sometimes have more then the first list.

thank you for taking your time.

Comment: First, it's not particularly obvious what `output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(input, i))) for i in range(len(input) + 1)], [])` is doing; you should maybe explain that. Second, it's really unclear what you are trying to achieve. You're "not sure that A1+B3+C2 is the best combo" for what?

Comment: I'm going to also say that I'm confused.  It is not clear from your description what it is you're trying to calculate.

Comment: @Stef 

My goal is to calculate the best combination of numbers which is a weight.
Im trying to calculte all the combinations possible for them to have the lowest diviation between them.
Im sorry for  not being so clearn as i am still new to asking questions here

Comment: @FrankYellin have a look and my comment

Comment: First f all I would like to point out that as described a, b, c are not lists they are dictionaries. Now can you explain what is an 'index' in this computation?  Can you explain what you mean by a deviation? Can you explain how the permutations of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] relate to the three dictionaries?

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear, it's really difficult to figure out what you are trying to do. I'm guessing that you have three different sets of numbers and you intend to consider all the possible triplets that would be obtained by picking one number at a time from each set. Then you want to compute the range of the results obtained by summing up the triplets.

First off, we create a list with your dictionaries (notice that in your question `a`, `b` and `c` are dictionaries rather than lists):

```py
In [22]: dicts = [a, b, c]
```

The size of this list is not limited to 3. I you had more dictionaries you can create a longer list, for example `discts = [a, b, c, d, e, ...]`.

Then we store the vlues of the dictionaries in a list of lists:

```py
In [23]: data = [list(letter.values()) for letter in dicts]

In [24]: data
Out[24]: [[10, 12, 14], [5, 4, 8], [6, 7, 3]]
```

We are now ready to generate all the possible triplets and the corresponding sums. To that end, [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) comes in handy:

```py
In [25]: from itertools import product

In [26]: combos = {triplet: sum(triplet) for triplet in product(*data)}

In [27]: combos
Out[27]: 
{(10, 5, 6): 21,
 (10, 5, 7): 22,
 (10, 5, 3): 18,
 (10, 4, 6): 20,
 (10, 4, 7): 21,
 (10, 4, 3): 17,
 (10, 8, 6): 24,
 (10, 8, 7): 25,
 (10, 8, 3): 21,
 (12, 5, 6): 23,
 (12, 5, 7): 24,
 (12, 5, 3): 20,
 (12, 4, 6): 22,
 (12, 4, 7): 23,
 (12, 4, 3): 19,
 (12, 8, 6): 26,
 (12, 8, 7): 27,
 (12, 8, 3): 23,
 (14, 5, 6): 25,
 (14, 5, 7): 26,
 (14, 5, 3): 22,
 (14, 4, 6): 24,
 (14, 4, 7): 25,
 (14, 4, 3): 21,
 (14, 8, 6): 28,
 (14, 8, 7): 29,
 (14, 8, 3): 25}
```

Finally, the range of results can be calculated as follows:

```py
In [28]: max(combos.values()) - min(combos.values())
Out[28]: 12
```

Side note: `input`is a built-in function in Python. Don't use `input` to name a function or variable!